# Balancing three parameters, so that when one of them changes, the amount does not change

Tags: java, python, math

I need to balance the three variables so that when adding a value to one of them, the others change proportionally so that the amount remains original.
For example, body triangle in Fallout 4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oNqT.jpg

I tried something, but it's not correct and actually doesn't work. 
At first, I simply add the missing quantity to other variables, but there is no proportionality. 
At second i'm tried to balance by proportioning:

```java
public class Triangle()
{
    float a = 0.33f;
    float b = 0.33f;
    float c = 0.33f;

    static float sum = 0.99f;
    static float maxVal = 0.97f;

    void AddA(float value)  {
        if (a + value <= maxVal) {
            a += value;         

            float ratio1 = b/sum;
            float ratio2 = c/sum;

            // difference between needed sum and current
            float remainderSum = a+b+c-sum;
            // the excess part is proportional to b
            float rem1 = remainderSum*ratio1;
            // the excess part is proportional to c
            float rem2 = remainderSum*ratio2;
            // subtract excess
            b -= rem1;
            c -= rem2;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Add(0.5f); =>
  Sum: 1.1566666666666665
  ABC: 0.8300000000000001/0.16333333333333325/0.16333333333333325
```

but in result sum not correct.

Comment: What language are you wanting to do this in, OP? You put both Java and C# tags on your post.

Comment: "I tried something, but it's not correct and actually doesn't work." Please show us what you tried, and explain in what way it doesn't work. That way we can help you to fix your code, rather than just writing it for you.

Comment: @Ethan because i use both and in what language will be the implementation does not matter

Comment: Go ahead and show what you tried; otherwise there's nothing for us to help you with here.  Your general algorithm should be for any input to x,y,or z calculate the difference between the old value and the new value (we'll call it 'delta'), and then add -0.5*delta to the other two terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Param3:

    MAX = 300

    a = 100
    b = 100
    c = 100
    
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = MAX-a-b
        
    def add_A(val):
        # Limitation
        if a+val > MAX:
            val = MAX-a
            print("A > MAX, must be <=")
        elif a+val < 0:
            val = -a
            print("A < 0, must be >=")
        
        a += val
        var coef = b/(b+c)
        b -= val*coef
        c = MAX - a - b
```

Comment: Why are you adding a bunch of code without explanation in python to a question about a Java program?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt because that's my own really old question and I really don't know why is it in Java. Just posted if someone (or myself more likely) will need it.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you increase one variable by one you want to decrease the two other variables. If you decrease them by a half each, the sum of all three variables stays the same.

pseudocode:

```
total = 1; //you could change this to anything

x = total/3;
y = total/3;
z = total/3;

def increaseX(amount) {
    x = x + amount;
    y = y - amount/2;
    z = z - amount/2;
}

def increaseY(amount) {
    y = y + amount;
    x = x - amount/2;
    z = z - amount/2;
}

def increaseZ(amount) {
    z = z + amount;
    x = x - amount/2;
    y = y - amount/2;
}
```

Comment: Ok, apparently I myself have complicated the task. Thanks.